# How would you find a character in a string in x86-64 assembly?

Tags: parsing, assembly, x86-64

I am wondering how I can point to a specific character in a string, then loop though the string to compare the character in the string with a specific charcter.

Comment: which programming language? For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @5th Assembly is tagged...

Comment: Look for a tutorial if you have no idea how to start. If you have a specific problem, post what you have so far and describe your difficulty in details.

Comment: [Finding substring in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364692/608639), [Agner Fog's strstr() vs g++ built-in strstr() performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48601519/608639), [How to compare a char in a string with another char in NASM x86_64 Linux assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35927302/608639), etc.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, according to the tag there is `java` or `.NET` flavour to it. But yeah I thought the assembly-tag means some sort of process

Comment: @5th Nah, it's warning people that it is incorrect to use this tag if you are referring to .net's DLL (called Assemblies) or for ASM, the Java library used for JVM bytecode manipulation.